# Ionic slow boot on android with –prod “enabled”

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I made a relatively small app I built it with this command to make it an .aab at the same time `ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle`. It is 3.7 MB on Android, which also means that it shouldn’t take that long to load, and yet from cold start it takes 30 seconds to load the app. This is not a problem on iOS, only Android. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

It is really a confusing question. Lets think about some points.

Let s define what is a “faster phone”: Any given generation, Apple usually has better (single-core) CPU performance and uses much faster flash than any Android OEM (though Samsung comes close). Apple’s chocie of GPU is usually top-shelf, too.

Single-core CPU performance and storage speed have a lot to do with how “fast” a phone “feels”: most phone apps don’t benefit from multithreading, so Apple’s fast cores make a big difference in immediate response, and having fast flash allows the device to load programs and swap memory very quickly.

On the software front, iOS runs a lot leaner than Android—apps and the OS need less memory—and the OS more heavily prioritizes foreground tasks and the input thread. Android, by contrast, multitasks better, but isn’t as responsive.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with it, because it is a general issue with ionic. No matter what modern phone you have it should be able to load a 3.7 MB app in way under 30 sec